# Macros to return defined(X) as true or false

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'd like a sequence of macros to replace the following code

```
#ifdef FOO
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
```

with something like

```
return MAGICLY_EXPANDING_IFDEFINED_MACRO(FOO);
```

As you can guess, there are a lot of FOOs, enough that shrinking 4 lines to 1 would be cool. But really it would be replacing a monster switch statement with one line.

Comment: Is `FOO` undefined (and redefined) somewhere?

Comment: Either `FOO` is undefined, or it has been set with a simple `#define FOO`. (It's a compilation option.)

Comment: The question is tagged both c and c++. Which language are you using?

Comment: C++, although for the preprocessor I don't think this file has any particularly C++ features. So I figured C gurus would have as good an answer.

Comment: There is no way to use a non existing symbol asides in #ifdef/#if defined

Comment: is it always `return true` or `return false`?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus also, what values are those defines given?

Comment: @PiotrS. Yes, and even if not, that could be handled by a caller. They aren't actually given values, a simple #define, or more likely a -D from compilation command line.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: Aww, you changed the question by mentioning `-D` compiler option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, the behavior of `defined` is specified only for conditional inclusion (`#if` and `#elif`).  So you cannot use it in any other way.

(The relevant rules are found in section 16.1 of the Standard)

But, if you want to detect macros that specifically are `#define` to the empty string, you don't need `defined()`, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

/* this matches */
#define FOO

/* this will not */
#undef BAZ

/* nor will these */
#define BAR 0
//#define BAR 1

#define STRINGIZE(x) (#x)
#define EXPAND_IF_DEFINED(y) (!*STRINGIZE(y))

int main()
{
    std::cout << +EXPAND_IF_DEFINED(FOO) << '\n'
              << +EXPAND_IF_DEFINED(BAR) << '\n'
              << +EXPAND_IF_DEFINED(BAZ) << '\n';
}
```

Warning, the `-D` option will not be an empty string.  To handle that case, you could use something like

```
#define IS_MACRO_DEFINED_OR_ONE(y) (!*STRINGIZE(y) || '1'==*STRINGIZE(y))
```

An even stronger test would be

```
#define IS_MACRO_DEFINED_NOT_TO_ITSELF(y) strcmp(#y, STRINGIZE(y))
```

Since literals are compile-time constants, the compiler will probably optimize that `strcmp` call during compilation to a constant `true` or `false`.  You could also make a `constexpr` version of `strcmp` to use.

Comment: And you can probably write a script that, given a list of the macro names, will generate C code like the above for each one.

Comment: That's basically the purpose of the existing switch, with an #if / #else for each.

Comment: The `strcmp` version is awesome.  It even works for `#define FOO "FOO"` and GCC eliminates the function call already at default optimization level.  Of course, we can easily write our own `constexpr strcmp(const char * a, const char * b)` as you've mentioned if we need a compile-time constant.

Comment: If only I could upvote twice... still fails in some corner cases like `#define FOO FOO`, but this is better than mine

Comment: @PiotrS.: I chose the name `IS_MACRO_DEFINED_NOT_TO_ITSELF` to make that a "surprising feature", not a bug.

Comment: @BenVoigt This doesn't seem to work in VS2017. I checked using `gcc -E` and `cl /E` switches, and for an empty declaration `#define FOO`, this `EXPAND_IF_DEFINED(FOO)` expands to `(!*(""))` in GCC but to `(!*())` in VS, which is a syntax error... Is it specified in the C/C++ standard how an empty macro is stringized?

Answer (score 5):

For simple defines like `#define FOO` or `#define FOO 1` the below macros will work well, but much more universal solution is in @BenVoigt 's answer.

```
#define MAGICLY_EXPANDING_IFDEFINED_MACRO_I(X) (#X[0] == 0 || #X[0] == '1')
#define MAGICLY_EXPANDING_IFDEFINED_MACRO(X) MAGICLY_EXPANDING_IFDEFINED_MACRO_I(X)
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbefb912a119308d)

---

#### *Q&A section*

> *How it works?*

That weird `#`-something stringifies either the value of define, or the define name itself (if one is not defined). As such, for defined `FOO` (with empty content) the compiler ends up with condition:

```
(""[0] == 0 || ""[0] == '1')
```

while for undefined `FOO` the condition is:

```
("FOO"[0] == 0 || "FOO"[0] == '1')
```

That `== 0` part matches the `\0` character ending each *raw string literal* (even that empty one `""`), while the `== '1'` condition is there in case someone defines value `1`, like in `#define FOO 1`

Comment: I admire your solution but I cannot figure out how it works.  Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @5gon12eder: Two layers of macros are required, to give the processor a chance to replace a name that is defined before stringizing takes place.  The `#` is the preprocessor stringizing operator, which basically throws double-quotes around the macro argument named.  So in my answer, `EXPAND_IF_DEFINED(FOO)` becomes `!*STRINGIZE()` becomes `!*""`.  But `EXPAND_IF_DEFINED(BAZ)` becomes `!*STRINGIZE(BAZ)` becomes `!*"BAZ"`.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.  But the approach has the obvious limitation that you (@BenVoigt) are listing in your answer.  If we `#define FOO 42` it gives a false negative.  This could be improved a little by using `(#X[0] == 0 || (#X[0] >= '0') && (#X[0] <= '9'))` so at least, all `#define FOO <NUMBER>` are detected correctly since `[0-9]` isn't a valid macro identifier begin anyway.

Comment: @5gon12eder see the comments under the question where I asked about possible values of define prior to posting my answer

Comment: I was agreeing that a test for digits was the best possible, then I realized it wasn't.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are generally a bad route. What are you trying to accomplish? Something like this would work:

```
//Stash this away in a header file
#ifndef FOO
#define RETURN false
#else
#define RETURN true
#endif

return RETURN;
```

Comment: I have `FOO`, `FOO1`, ... `FOO100`.

Comment: But why? Why use macros when you have templates or variables?

Comment: Legacy code, but it's all conditional compilation. Basically, 'Does this executable support feature X'?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately for sanity's sake) you cannot embed preprocessor directives inside of macros.